# Data abstraction in set theory via Urelements

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, type-theory, proof-assistants

I am working in a setting of set theory where set theory is embedded in simply-typed higher-order logic, basically as described for example in

> Chad E. Brown and Cezary Kaliszyk and Karol Pak (2019) *Higher-Order Tarski Grothendieck as a Foundation for Formal Proof*, In: John Harrison and John O'Leary and Andrew Tolmach (eds) 10th International Conference on Interactive Theorem Proving (ITP 2019), Leibniz International Proceedings in Informatics (LIPIcs) **141** pages 9:1--9:16,
> doi:[10.4230/LIPIcs.ITP.2019.9](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.ITP.2019.9)

or in

> Steven Obua (2006) *Partizan Games in Isabelle/HOLZF*, In: Barkaoui K., Cavalcanti A., Cerone A. (eds) Theoretical Aspects of Computing - ICTAC 2006. ICTAC 2006. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol **4281**. doi:[10.1007/11921240_19](https://doi.org/10.1007/11921240_19).

In particular, there is a type $\sigma$ that corresponds to the universe of sets, there is a type $\mathbb{P}$ of propositions, and there are types which are higher-order functions $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ for all types $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Classes can be represented in this setting by the type $\sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$, for example.

Unlike in the referenced papers, I would also like to allow *urelements*, that is values of type $\sigma$ which are not sets. I am wondering now if the following axiomatic addition would be somehow (obviously?) inconsistent:

---

*EDIT: Due to the inconsistency of the original axioms uncovered by the comment of **François G. Dorais**, I changed the axioms in the following*.

---

**Assume that we have a higher-order function $\operatorname{Box} : \sigma \rightarrow \sigma$ which sends sets to urelements in an unambiguous way.**

We leave $\operatorname{Box}$ unspecified on urelements, and the above can then be expressed more formulaic as follows:

1. Define $\operatorname{Set} : \sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ via $\operatorname{Set}(x) = (x = \emptyset \vee \exists y : \sigma.\, y \in x)$
2. Define $\operatorname{Ur} : \sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ via $\operatorname{Ur}(x) = \lnot \operatorname{Set}(x)$
3. $\forall x : \sigma.\, \operatorname{Set}(x) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Ur}(\operatorname{Box}(x))$
4. $\forall x : \sigma.\, \forall y : \sigma.\,(\operatorname{Set}(x) \wedge \operatorname{Set}(y) \wedge \operatorname{Box}(x) = \operatorname{Box}(y)) \longrightarrow x = y$

Obviously the other axioms of set theory have to be adapted to account for urelements, but apart from that, would it be OK to add these axioms?

The background for my question is that I would like to use set theory as the basis of [a mechanised theorem proving system](http://practal.com), but a big problem of set theory as opposed to type theory in that setting is data abstraction. Having a function $\operatorname{Box}$ at my disposal should solve that problem.

Comment: Actually, looking at the definition, I don't see a reason not to declare $\emptyset$ an urelement as well, so an alternative definition of $\operatorname{Ur}$ could be:
$$\operatorname{Ur}(x) = \forall y : \sigma.\,y \notin x$$

Comment: There's no issue unless you want the urelements to form a set. In that case, the injectivity requirement will be problematic.

Comment: That's great to hear! No, I don't need the urelements to form a set.

Comment: Do you intend to allow $\mathrm{Box}$ to be used in separation instances in your basic set-theory or is it just an addition on top?

Comment: It is an addition on top, but you could use it in separation or replacement, as these are modelled via constants $\operatorname{Sep} : \sigma \rightarrow (\sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow \sigma$ and  $\operatorname{Repl} : \sigma \rightarrow (\sigma \rightarrow \sigma) \rightarrow \sigma$ with the axioms:
$$(a \in \operatorname{Sep} A\, p) = (a \in A \wedge p\,a)$$
$$(b \in \operatorname{Repl} A\,f) = (\exists a : \sigma. b = f\,a \wedge a \in A)$$ and $p$ and $f$ could have been defined involving $\operatorname{Box}$.

Comment: And given $\operatorname{Set} : \sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ with 
$$\operatorname{Set}(x) = (x = \emptyset \vee \exists y. y \in x)$$
there would also need to be the additional axioms $$\operatorname{Set}(\operatorname{Sep} A\, p)$$ and $$\operatorname{Set}(\operatorname{Repl} A\, f)$$

Comment: Actually, there is a problem: for any $x$ we have $\operatorname{Box}(\operatorname{Box}(x)) = \operatorname{Box}(x)$ by 2 & 3, but then $\operatorname{Box}(x) = x$ by 4. I recommend dropping 3.

Comment: Oh. Great catch. I really only need the behaviour of $\operatorname{Box}$ on sets, so dropping 3. sounds good to me. Maybe I should make $\operatorname{Box}$ as unspecified as possible, so not only dropping 3., but also predicate all the laws on sets, to give:

$$\forall x.\,\operatorname{Set}(x) \rightarrow \operatorname{Ur}(\operatorname{Box}(x))$$
$$\forall x\,y.\,\operatorname{Set}(x) \rightarrow \operatorname{Set}(y) \rightarrow \operatorname{Box}(x) =  \operatorname{Box}(y) \rightarrow x = y$$
together with the definitions of $\operatorname{Set}$ and $\operatorname{Ur}$.

Comment: Actually, as I intend to embed the set theory in a simply-typed higher order logic that allows undefinedness, I should make $\operatorname{Box}$ just undefined for non-sets.

Comment: My feeling from where another inconsistency could come from is that there are "not enough" urelements to go around. There are at least as many urelements as there are sets because of 3. and 4., but on the other hand each urelement $u$ forms a singleton set $\{u\}$ and thus there are also at least as many sets as there are urelements. But it feels there are just so many more sets than just singleton sets. But on the other hand, for each set $s$ one can also form the singleton set $\{s\}$, so that is probably a wrong intuition.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "data abstraction"? As in programming language "abstract data type", or something else? How is $\mathrm{Box}$ solving any problems in formalization?

Comment: Yes, as in programming language abstract data type. Consider for example ordered pairs. In the usual set theory, ordered pairs are still sets, although this is not relevant at all for ordered pairs. The only properties relevant for ordered pairs are for how they behave under projections etc. With the Box function, you can apply it to your ordinary ordered pair construction, and it will not be a set anymore.

Comment: It's not that you can now suddenly formalise things you couldn't formalise before. But people were bringing this up anyway as a negative when considering set theory for practical formalisations. I thought you would be one of those people.

Comment: You are not solving your problem because $\mathrm{Box}(\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\})$ is just as transparent (non-abstract) as anything else in your language. One can still extract the argument of $\mathrm{Box}$ easily: if $u$ is known to be boxed then we can get to what is inside $u$ with $\exists x . \mathrm{Box}(x) = u \land \cdots$. The problem goes deeper: there is nothing in first-order logic that allows abstraction. You just cannot do it this way. You have to use some meta-level mechanisms, such as definitions of new symbols, with the ability to hide the definitions.

Comment: I would also remark that, if your goal is to formalize mathematics as done by actual mathematicians, then you shouldn't just blindly believe those who say they're using set theory to do informal mathematics. They're using *something like set theory*, but not first-order logic with set theory. For instance, everyone uses definitions, but also a lot of machinery that goes beyond first-order logic and formal set theory.

Comment: Yes, you need those mechanisms, but that is easy to do in a theorem proving system. Before though, even those mechanisms could not hide that your ordered pair was a set. Now you can. If that axiom isn't somehow inconsistent, that is.

Comment: Oh, I know how I like to do math. And I want a system that does it like that.

Comment: Well, go ahead, build one :-)

Answer (score 2):

In their [CICM 2020](https://cicm-conference.org/2020/cicm.php) paper

> Dunne C., Wells J.B., Kamareddine F. (2020) *Adding an Abstraction Barrier to ZF Set Theory*. In: Benzmüller C., Miller B. (eds) Intelligent Computer Mathematics. CICM 2020. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 12236. Springer, Cham. doi:[10.1007/978-3-030-53518-6_6](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-53518-6_6)

the authors introduce ZFP, which is ZF set theory with a primitive notion of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ which are not sets, i.e. they are urelements. They also create a model for ZFP (even in Isabelle/ZF).

Obviously, ZFP can be obtained as a special case via the $\operatorname{Box}$ function:
$$(x, y) = \operatorname{Box}(\{x, \{x, y\}\})$$
But, as pointed out to me by Mario Carneiro in a CICM 2020 discussion channel, the other direction is maybe even more obvious as $\operatorname{Box}$ can be defined in terms of ordered pairs:
$$\operatorname{Box}(x) = (x, x)$$

Thus, the model of ZFP also induces a model for $\operatorname{Box}$, and thus boxing is consistent relative to ZF set theory.

Comment: Does this not beg the question: why only admit pairs as primitive, and not other objects, such as elements of disjoint sums and quotients?

Comment: You can just consider it as a convenient tool to provide consistency for free because the ZFP paper has already been written. You can use $\operatorname{Box}$ to construct all sorts of data types.